# Clevo keyboard backlight won't turn off after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, backlight

When I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, my laptop keyboard backlight got stuck as permanently on. The extension I was using to control the backlight, clevo-keyboard-gnome-extension, "is incompatible with your current version of GNOME." I also tried using brightnessctl to turn off the light, but my keyboard backlight isn't in the list of controllable lights.
Has anyone else had a similar problem? I would prefer if I could find a solution that doesn't mean downgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, since the internet says that's difficult to do. I don't suppose it's possible to physically cut off power to the keyboard backlight without breaking the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to reinstall the drivers from the company that sold me the computer. The instructions are here: https://junocomputers.com/us/support/

I guess the drivers should work with Ubuntu 22.04, but I ended up doing a clean install of 20.04 because I like it better. The install wasn't nearly as difficult as I was anticipating, it just took several hours to back my files up with Deja Dup before I started.